# SharePoint 2013 Get difference between two dates in days using JavaScript/J query

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, date-time

I want to get the difference in days between two dates. One date is from a List item input by User. The second day will be "Today". get the number of days from the date input by user and current day.

Will this work?

```
var onBoardDate = value.OnBoardDate; //value obtained via REST call

var today = new Date(); // current day
var dateToString2 = today;
var dateDiff = dateToString2 - dateToString1;
console.log(dateDiff);

var date_diff_indays = function (date1, date2) {
  dt1 = dateToString1;
  dt2 = dateToString2;
  return Math.floor((Date.UTC(dt2.getFullYear(), dt2.getMonth(), dt2.getDate()) - Date.UTC(dt1.getFullYear(), dt1.getMonth(), dt1.getDate())) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
console.log(date_diff_indays(dt1, dt2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are some syntax errors in your code like:

1. `dateToString1` is not defined anywhere.
2. Arguments/Parameters you are passing and using in `date_diff_indays()` function are different.

Check below question on Stack Overflow to get the number of days between two dates:

[How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: The date I retrieve via REST Call from a SharePoint date picker field, what format is it in?
Do I need to change the format of the date picker field?

Comment: It depends on which solution you use. Retrieved date will be in ISO date format. You can create date object from it simply by using `var onBoardDate = new Date(value.OnBoardDate);`.